# JavaFX lineChart issue

Tags: java, javafx

i have following code:

```
 final TreeMap<Integer, Double> ADLMap = new TreeMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

  @Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    final String currency = "currreny";
    ADL(currency);
    stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
    //defining the axes
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
    //creating the chart
    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    //defining a series
    XYChart.Series ADLChart = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series regularChart = new XYChart.Series();

    ADLChart.setName("My portfolio");

    chartMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> regularChart.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));

    //populating the series with data
    ADLMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> ADLChart.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));
    System.out.println(ADLMap);
    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);

    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 1200, 1000);
    //lineChart.getData().add(regularChart);
    lineChart.getData().add(ADLChart);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


    final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
    lineChart.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            event.consume();

            if (event.getDeltaY() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            double scaleFactor = (event.getDeltaY() > 0) ? SCALE_DELTA : 1 / SCALE_DELTA;

            lineChart.setScaleX(lineChart.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
            lineChart.setScaleY(lineChart.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
        }
    });

    lineChart.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                lineChart.setScaleX(1.0);
                lineChart.setScaleY(1.0);
            }
        }
    });

}

   private void ADL(final String currency) {
    double counter = -4000000.0;
    int mapCounter = 0;
    while (counter < 4000000) {
        ADLMap.put(mapCounter++, counter++);
    }
}
```

the Map contains following values:
keys n+1 n€IN
Values from range from -10.000.000 to + 10.000.000

**My Problem:** It doesn't plot values at all. At least i cannot see any.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you [edit] this so it makes a [MCVE]? Pretty much all you need to do is define and populate the maps with hardcoded or random data. The other people can run it and see the issue, and will be assured the problem doesn't arise from your data. (FWIW if I do that myself it works fine..)

Comment: I am sorry! I edited my code. Is it okay like that?
P.S: I tested the Map content etc. It looks like the problem are the large value numbers?

Comment: You have 8 million data points????

Comment: Y-Axis is ranging from  -4.000.000 to +4.000.000 yes. the graph could also only have 100 X-Axsis-points but Y still can be everything in that million range, yes.

Comment: The problem is not the range of the y-axis: the problem is the actual number of points. Every point in the chart is represented by a UI node. This probably works... it would just take a very very long time and a large amount of memory to display. Does it work if you only have 100 points?

Comment: I am sorry, it looks like the complex algorthm in ADL() produces an inifnity value which is tried to be plotted in the chart. That causes the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake was that a complex algorithm produced an inifnity nuber which was placed in the TreeMap. The Graph couldn't plot it ofc.